# jQuery slideToggle() issue

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a navigation that has a mobile and desktop version. The layout is fine and for most part the functionality is working but I am having an issue with `slideToggle()`.

When the screen is below 768 for example, the navigation expand button appears and clicking on an li toggles the main nav to close the navigation on mobile. When I resize the window clicking upon the main nav continues to toggle even though it is above 768.

Any help is appreciated :)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="mobileNav">
        <li>Expand</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mainNav">
        <li class="">Item1</li>
        <li class="">Item2</li>
        <li class="">Item3</li>
        <li class="">Item4</li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var expand = $('.mobileNav li');
    menu = $('.mainNav');

    $(expand).click(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();

        if (width < 768) {
            menu.slideToggle();

            $('.mainNav li').click(function() {
                menu.slideUp();
            });         
        }
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

1. You should not register the click event on another click event handler, it will make the click event handler to execute multiple times
2. You are not checking the width inside the second click handler

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var expand = $('.mobileNav li');
    menu = $('.mainNav');

    $(expand).click(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 768) {
            menu.slideToggle();
        }
    });     
    $('.mainNav li').click(function() {
        if (width < 768) {
            menu.slideUp();
        }
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another event for window resize

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var width = $(window).width();
   if (width > 768) {
       menu.show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following `css` to toggle div

```
width:100%!important;
```

Reason: While there is no width define the slideToggle will make width and height to 0 and display:none

and expanding mode, it will do visa versa, width is going to increase to parent div width, content is expanding and the height at that position is more than what is required at final stage

when finally width made to 100% the height will reset to what it required